# Permission Denied with crontab

Tags: linux, bash, cron, linux-mint

I try to execute a script (on my personal pc, Linux Mint) who execute two other scripts who launch two servers (one script for a Symfony server and one for a webpack server) using cron. So I put this line inside my crontab

```
@reboot /usr/local/bin/launchFm.sh 2>&1 ~/Documents/script/errorcron
```

inside ~/Documents/script/errorcron file I got this line

> Unable to init server: Impossible de se connecter : Connexion refusée

Yeah I'm french but it's basically connection denied.

I can execute this script by manullay and it works fine. Also, I tried to execute a dummy script inside the crontab like `@reboot touch test`, and this work perfectly fine. I have no cron.deny or cron.allow file.

I got this permission for the /usr/local/bin/launchFm.sh `-rwxr-xr-x` and I'm the owner. So everybody got the x(execute) permission. The error says `Unable to init server` but I got nothing inside the error log of the script who launch server so I think the problem is the crontab permission but basic script work fine so I'm very confuse

Comment: Try `sudo /usr/local/bin/launchFm.sh 2>&1 ~/Documents/script/errorcron`

Comment: I wish it was that simple but no

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by calling the two scripts instead of calling the script who execute the two "subscript". It's not elegant but it work.